# Designing a social networking website-DB and Front end?

Tags: social-networking

I am working on a social networking website which requires person-to-person connections & relationships(of different level) to be stored and retrieved in Database in efficient manner?

May I know answer to following questions:-
i) Any idea which is best database (in terms of easiness and efficient queries) for these kind of projects?
ii) Any idea what orkut/facebook might be use at DB side?
iii) Any idea what technology should I choose for front end to give it up-to-date social-networking-site-look-and-feel?

Answer (score 0):

1) Depends on your use cases and on how you plan to fetch data back.
2) It doesn't really matter because they most probably could have done it on anything and later on change as the site grew. That's because their problem #1 is not implementing the features but scaling.
3) html + css

Comment: 3) I know html+css is after all what everthing is ended up in. But don't u think this make dev process very cumbersome and time consuming. Have you ever thought :- sites like facebook/orkut, what development process for front-end, they might be using. ?

Comment: css based layout has a steeper learning curve than the ancient table based layout, but in the end it pays of heavily.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question regarding what Facebook uses for it's DB etc. There servers run a LAMP Stack with a lot of custom compiled services running on the back-end. Check out this link for more info:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/

Comment: Thanks for link. In my college days, I remember myself reading somehwere that "XYZ" database is invention of facebook IT dept. I don't remember that DB name exactly. But it was in relation of graph based Database. My understanding is that a social networking based data(person-to-person connection) can be thought of a graph so it needs more that usual relational DB. Right? Any book/link you think provide insight into same?

Comment: @ag112: I was answering on the db that facebook invented which you could not remember the name of.

Comment: It was Cassandra. Facebook has actually spawned many technological innovation due to their need for extreme scalability. They have released thje majority to the open source world.